# Update kernel with MOK enrolled and secure boot activated

Tags: linux-kernel, secure-boot

I've enrolled some MOKs to sign several modules (they only print in the systemd log).
The keys are visible in `/proc/keys` so they are kernel dependent.
I'll update the kernel via `apt` and I'm not sure if the keys will be loaded in the new version.
With a manual update is it possible to load the old keys and keyrings?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.